# Proving $\sum_{s \in S} \frac{1}{n}$ converges for $S = \{ s \in \mathbb{N} : s$ has no zeros on its decimal representation $\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, proof-verification

Consider $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ as the set of numbers which do not have the algarism $0$ on its decimal representation. For instance:
$$S=\{1,2, \dots, 9, 11, 12,\dots, 19, 21, 22, \dots\}$$
 I want to prove that:

$$(1) \sum_{n \in S} \frac{1}{n}$$

converges using [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series).

I am considering

$$\int\sum_{n \in S} \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n \in S} \int \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) = \sum_{n \in S} \ln\left(n\right)$$

I've discovered (by simple combinatorics) that I can write, in terms of $n$, the following

$$\sum_{n \in S} n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \left( 1 + \dots + 9\right)\sum^{n-1}_{i = 0}\sum^{n-1}_{j = i}10^{i}9^{j} \right)$$

but couldn't find any better way to write this up.

From the result above I get

$$(2) \sum_{n \in S} \ln\left(n\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n\ln\left(9!\right) + 9\left(\sum^{n-1}_{i = 0}\sum^{n-1}_{j = i}i\ln\left(10\right) + j\ln\left(9\right)\right)\right)$$

Now, to finish the proof, one needs to derivate $(2)$ on both sides and see the result of $(1)$ is a constant. But, formely, how can I derivate the big parentesis on $(2)$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{s\in S}1/s$? Also, what do you mean by that integral? There is no variable to be integrated out...

Comment: @mge Yeah I did mean that sum. Have corrected it now. Hope I didn't mess up any more indices. By that integral I mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration I'm proving the convergence using power series.

Comment: For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series

Comment: @ivanneretin I wasn't convinced with wikipedia's proof, so I searched for the original publication and here it is: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2972074.pdf?_=1461764715062 But there is something very important: A. J. Kempner said himself that his proof can't be applied without modifications for the figure $0$... and I'm asking myself why he said that, since it seems you can use the same logic for the zero case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of $n \in S$ with $N$ digits is $9^N$.
These will contribute $< 9^N/10^{N-1}$ to $\sum_{n \in S} 1/n$.
The result follows since $\sum_N (9/10)^N$ converges.